# login system with a phone authentication system using twilio

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, twilio, firebase-realtime-database, ngcordova

I'm trying to build a login system with a phone authentication system. 
Does anyone of you have experience with this? I'm using fire base as a backend, and twilio for sending sms. So i need to send sms with a pin. i'm developing this app using (ionic + firebase + twilio)

Thanks

Comment: When you say you're using "cloud" as a backend, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: cloud means firebase database

Comment: When you say they have Twilio integrated in cloud, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you point me to the integration docs? Thanks.

Comment: when i register new user a authentication pin sms sent to his mobile no.

Comment: Are you running your own server at all?

Comment: no im using fire base.

Comment: Did you get this to work for you in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to send SMS messages using Twilio you're going to need your own server so that you can make the API requests to the Twilio API. I checked through Firebase and there is nowhere for you to run your own code on there, which is a shame, though it does supply static site hosting these days, which is nice.

I recommend you take a look through the [Twilio tutorials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials) which will give you a good idea how to build an application that can perform the API requests for you. I might start by checking out:

- [SMS notifications in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/server-notifications/node/express)
- [Phone authentication using Authy in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/account-verification/node/express)

([Authy](https://www.authy.com) is the best way of verifying and authenticating phone numbers and is part of Twilio now.)

Let me know if this helps at all.